# Identifying tagged graphs or networks with the same label or "color" structure

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like the following two graphs to be `SameQ`:

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5}, 
 {UndirectedEdge[1, 2, 1], 
  UndirectedEdge[3, 4, 1], 
  UndirectedEdge[6, 7, 2], 
  UndirectedEdge[4, 5, 2]}, 
 {EdgeLabels -> {"EdgeTag"}, 
  VertexLabels -> {6 -> "B", 
    3 -> "B", 5 -> "A", 
    7 -> "A", 4 -> "B", 
    2 -> "A", 1 -> "A"}}]
```

[image]

and

```
Graph[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, {UndirectedEdge[a, b, 2], 
   UndirectedEdge[c, d, 1], UndirectedEdge[f, g, 1], 
   UndirectedEdge[d, e, 2]}, {EdgeLabels -> {"EdgeTag"}, 
   VertexLabels -> {f -> "A", c -> "B", e -> "A", g -> "A", d -> "B", 
     b -> "B", a -> "A"}}]
```

[image]

Because they have the same label structure up to a permutation in the order of the disconnected graphs and because the edges are undirected. Or in a sentence : because the graphs look the same with a B-B-A then an A-B then a A-A regardless of the order they are in. Note that I considered simple chains here which is what I am working with at the moment but in the future I might have to upgrade to graphs that have vertices with a higher connectivity degree although they should not have any loops or multiple edges.

**EDIT :** Ideally I would like a canonical form for both.

`IGBlissCanonicalGraph` from the

```
IGraphM`
```

package does nearly that using vertex colors but it removes the edge tags. Is there a way to identify the graphs above while preserving the edge tags ? Maybe I should drop the edge tags and consider something else ? Maybe I should work with a dual graph instead ?

**Note** that the vertex label categories A and B makes the problem more restrictive than just checking if the graphs verify `IsomorphicGraphQ`

**EDIT :** I learned that VF2 in IGraphM works with edge colors, I am checking if I can make a dictionary with edge tags.

VF2 might work but it does not offer a canonical form. If no one answers then I will add that turning the graphs to molecules and using methods to identify molecules is what I did in the past for this problem but the method is slow when working with thousands of graphs.

Comment: `SameQ[EdgeList[g1], EdgeList[g2]] (* True *)`

Comment: @Alan I might have chosen a bad choice but I can't rely on the values of the vertices they can be arbitrarily chosen with `Unique` for example. The only thing I can rely on is the labels. I will see if I can change my post and I will consider whether I can rewrite the code so that your suggestion would work.

Comment: IGraph/M has the VF2 algorithm which can handle edge colours. However, VF2 cannot produce a canonical labelling. It can merely determine if two graphs are isomorphic. Is this sufficient for you?  If not, the best approach is trying to think up an encoding of edge coloured graphs into purely vertex coloured graphs. For example, it might be worth thinking about whether subdividing each edge with a single vertex and assigning the edge colour to that vertex yields an equivalent problem. You would need to make sure that vertex and edge colours do not clash.

Comment: Ah, I see from your update that you found VF2. If you want the canonical form, I suggest you go with the edge subdivision approach. Note that I don't have time to think through the details and implement it today, so I won't post an answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs The edge subdivision sounds like a good idea. It sounds feasible enough that I might be able to implement it. I also have another idea of reducing the graph to it's color connectivity using`RelationshipGraph` regardless of the numbers/values in the vertices. Thanks for the idea I will see what it does.

Comment: I prefer a canonical form because the complexity for what I want would be O(n) instead of O(n^2) by checking Isomorphisms. The problem can have  even around a billion graphs  so that is important to me. I use the graphs as tensor expressions in sums and I can use that to simplify expressions instead of trying to figure out a way to relabel tensor indices while taking into account symmetries.

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you for that nice idea of introducing vertices in the edges. It worked for the example in the question and seems robust. There is quite a bit of code involved in translating from vertex labels and edge tags to colors and then back.

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry to bother. It seems like deleting the introduced vertices that represent the colors takes nearly half of the computation time. I recursively delete them with `Fold`. Perhaps you might know a more efficient way. At the moment it seems to require roughly two times less computer time to convert the graphs to molecules like I did before and identify molecules by their names.

Comment: I modified the code to try to contract all vertices at once but it seems that internally `VertexContract` just  calls "`Fold[GraphComputation`GraphContractDump`vertexContract[#1,#2]&,graph,GraphComputation`GraphContractDump`vertices]`" and so it seems to just Fold as I did.

Comment: @Szabolcs , in the event that the following information might be of any use to you, it turns out that using `SubsetReplace` on the `EdgeList` lead to a computation that was 3 times faster than using `VertexContract`, `EdgeDelete` and `EdgeAdd` to remove the introduced colored vertices and re-introduce tags on the edges. A more extensive and precise study would probably be needed to confirm whether one is generally quicker than the other. It's unfortunate that `Dispatch` does not seem to work with `SubsetReplace`

Answer (score 1):

@Szabolcs suggestion to introduce new vertices at the middle of the edges worked at least in this case.

I will explain the method and provide the code in the event that it is of use to someone else. Note that in the past I converted graphs to molecules and then used molecule nomenclature to obtain a canonical representation. If instead the reader just wants to check that the graphs are isomorphic while preserving labels of vertices and maybe edges,then they may use other functions in `IGraphM` or perhaps the molecule framework although I did not use it like that.

The idea is to find a canonical graph for a colored graph where the colors are represented by the labels on the graph. Specifically, there are colors that correspond to vertex labels and introduced auxiliary vertices that are "colored" according to the tag label. One may then use `IGBlissCanonicalGraph` from

```
IGraphM`
```

to get a canonical form for the auxiliary graph with introduced vertices labeling edge tags then remove them.

There is a lot of code involved in going back and forth between vertex labels and edge tags and the colored graph used by IGBlissCanonical Graph:

I used a helper function that acts as [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) but for graphs in the sense that it deletes a vertex and connects the adjacent vertices. The code also places the edge tag encoded by the vertex.

Note: `\[Ellipsis]=…`

```
vertexNothing[graph_,v_]:=
Module[{connected…vertices,result},

connected…vertices=
Rest@VertexInComponent[graph,{v[[1]]},1];

result=VertexContract[graph,{connected…vertices[[1]],v[[1]]}];

EdgeDelete[result,UndirectedEdge@@connected…vertices]
//EdgeAdd[#,UndirectedEdge@@Append[connected…vertices,v[[2]]]]&
]
```

Next install IGraphM from http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html

then load IGraphM

```
<< IGraphM`
```

Then the function that canonicalizes the graph:

```
canonicalize[graph_]:=
Module[{edges,new…edges,graph•mod,
introduced…vertices, new,
colors,graph•canonical•aux,
vertex…labels, rm…duplicates…vertex…labels,
labels,introduced…vertices…to…remove,
color…dictionary,edge…tags,
result,color…to…tag,new…labels},

edges=EdgeList@graph;
new…edges=
edges /. a_Overscript[\[UndirectedEdge], c_]b_:> Module[{label},
                        ##&[a\[UndirectedEdge]new[c,label],new[c,label]\[UndirectedEdge]b]
                        ]
;
(* replace previous edges with new…edges  *)
graph•mod=
EdgeDelete[graph,edges]
// EdgeAdd[#,new…edges] &
;
introduced…vertices=
Cases[VertexList@graph•mod, _new]
;
edge…tags=
introduced…vertices//Map[Last]//DeleteDuplicates ;
;
vertex…labels=
AnnotationValue[graph,VertexLabels]
;
rm…duplicates…vertex…labels=
Sort@DeleteDuplicates[vertex…labels[[All,2]]]
;
color…dictionary=
Thread[rm…duplicates…vertex…labels->
                       (rm…duplicates…vertex…labels 
                       //Length //Range)]
;
colors=
(vertex…labels/. color…dictionary)~
Join~(#->(Length@rm…duplicates…vertex…labels
          +#[[1]])&/@introduced…vertices) 
//Association
;
color…to…tag=Reverse/@Normal@colors /.new[a_,b_]:>a
;
graph•canonical•aux=
IGBlissCanonicalGraph[{graph•mod,"VertexColors"->colors}]
;
labels=
AnnotationValue[graph•canonical•aux,
                AnnotationRules]
// MapAt[Last@*Last,{All,2}]
;
introduced…vertices…to…remove=
Cases[labels,HoldPattern[s_->m_ 
                        /; m>Length@rm…duplicates…vertex…labels
                        ]
              :> {s,(m/. color…to…tag)}]
;
result=
Fold[vertexNothing,
graph•canonical•aux,
introduced…vertices…to…remove]
;
new…labels=
Select[#[[1]]<=Max[VertexList@result]&]@labels
;
AnnotationValue[result,VertexLabels]=
ReplaceAt[new…labels,Reverse/@color…dictionary,{All,2}]
;
Graph[result, DeleteCases[Options[graph],VertexLabels->_]]
]
```

**test :**

```
graph = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5}, {UndirectedEdge[1, 2, 1], 
UndirectedEdge[3, 4, 1], UndirectedEdge[6, 7, 2], 
UndirectedEdge[4, 5, 2]}, {EdgeLabels -> {"EdgeTag"}, 
VertexLabels -> {6 -> "B", 3 -> "B", 5 -> "A", 7 -> "A", 4 -> "B",
   2 -> "A", 1 -> "A"}}];


graph2 = 
  Graph[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, {UndirectedEdge[a, b, 2], 
    UndirectedEdge[c, d, 1], UndirectedEdge[f, g, 1], 
    UndirectedEdge[d, e, 2]}, {EdgeLabels -> {"EdgeTag"}, 
    VertexLabels -> {f -> "A", c -> "B", e -> "A", g -> "A", d -> "B",
       b -> "B", a -> "A"}}];

canonicalize[graph2]-canonicalize[graph] (* needs to be 
evaluated twice the first time for an unknown reason  *)
```

`(* 0 *)`